# XSLT: How to delete all nodes except ones having a child with certain value?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am trying to delete from an XML file, all the nodes that not satisfy certain condition.
This is my simplified input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<unit xmlns="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src">
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Row>
            <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
            <LastName>David</LastName>
            <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <FirstName>David</FirstName>
            <LastName>Michael</LastName>
            <Phone>01234567890</Phone>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <FirstName>Yang</FirstName>
            <LastName>Christina</LastName>
            <Phone>2345678901</Phone>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <FirstName>Grey</FirstName>
            <LastName>Meredith</LastName>
            <Phone>3456789012</Phone>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
            <LastName>Shepherd</LastName>
            <Phone>5678901234</Phone>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
<Tag>
    <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
    <LastName>Shepherd</LastName>
    <Phone>5678901234</Phone>
</Tag>
</unit>
```

I would like to write an XSLT transformation file that will be able to delete all the nodes that don't have a child of type `FirstName` with value `Michael`.
For the input I have just provided, I would like to obtain this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<unit xmlns="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src">
        <Row>
            <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
            <LastName>David</LastName>
            <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
            <LastName>Shepherd</LastName>
            <Phone>5678901234</Phone>
        </Row>
    <Tag>
        <FirstName>Michael</FirstName>
        <LastName>Shepherd</LastName>
        <Phone>5678901234</Phone>
    </Tag>
</unit>
```

This is the transformation file I have written up now:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src"
xmlns:src="http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
version="1.0">

<xsl:template name="removingNotMichael" match="*[child::src:FirstName[.= 'Michael']]">
<xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does not produce anything, just a completely empty file.
Could anybody please help me with this issue?

Comment: Look on Wikipedia for "identity transform" then add an _empty_ template that matches the stuff you want to remove.

Comment: @JimGarrison: If I have understood rightly, "identity transform" is what I do with `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>` while the _empty_ template is this one `<xsl:template match="@*|node()"/>`. Despite those, my output is what I have posted.

Comment: Your "empty" template matches all attributes (`@*`) and element, text, processing instruction, and comment nodes (`node()`) not matched by any other template. After matching, it doesn't do any other processing (there's no `xsl:apply-templates`). So what happens is the root element (`{http://www.srcML.org/srcML/src}unit`) gets matched and then nothing else gets processed. The identity transform uses `xsl:copy`, but that's not all it is. See here: https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Try this:

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
         <unit>
            <xsl:copy-of select="//*[src:FirstName = 'Michael']"/>
         </unit>
    </xsl:template>
```